# Featured images not appearing

Tags: wordpress, image, themes, blogs, wordpress-featured-image

So I’ve been struggling with this problem for a few weeks now. I’ve deactivated and reactivated every plug-in AND tested my theme to see if that was the cause (and it was not) but for some reason most of my featured images are not showing up and it’s terribly annoying since it messes with the way my posts appear on my blog.

I’m considering leaving WordPress if this does not get resolved soon.
The featured images on my blog will not appear. They can be uploaded and edited. I’ve rebuilt their thumbnails. They are just fine until I attach them to a post and then they won’t show.

The problem is when I set a featured image. I can click on an image I uploaded, but it won’t actually attach to the post. After I select a featured image, it says “Click the image to edit or update” or “Remove Image” but there isn’t a picture there and when I update or publish the page, still no picture. This isn’t the case across the board and I have no idea why about six pictures have worked and the others haven’t. I’ve resized them to be the same size, same picture quality, even similar names. I’ve tried it all. I don’t know what’s wrong.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no code or image is hard to understand what is happening. Could be a lot of things

1. The theme you have does not call those images or have to be called in a different manner. Check the theme manual or get another. (hardest way an not recommend to do it) revise the theme code to check if it does it.
2. Check that you are in the correct page, featured images are for **posts** check that you are not in a **page** url. Click on the url on top of the post to go directly to the post page. Also publish it before going to the post url.

Surelly there may be other thing to take in consideration, but these are the most common. Without more information of the problem is really hard to get a proper answer.